# Do Rj45 couplers slow down / create bottle necks in a network?

Tags: ethernet, rj-45

Do Rj45 couplers like the ones [here on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009PM9ME4?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00) below slow down a network / create bottle necks. Network switches are specced as gigabit or 10/100, but i havnt seen any couplers specced as such, is this because they are essentially a connection block ?

Comment: well, any coupler will increase noise on the line, but that shouldn't really be an issue unless the part is very poorly made, or you are using it to exceed length limitations implicit in the ethernet spec. Connectors like these have no circuitry or logic, so there is no need for a speed rating like 10/100/1000. they operate at the speed of electricity, whereas switches/routers operate at the speed the protocol designates based on its requirements like CSMA\CD hello time (the time it takes a signal to traverse the lenght of a bus network and reflect to the sender.)

Comment: *"i havnt seen any couplers specced as such"* -- The inline coupler should have a bandwidth specification similar to UTP cable, e.g. for Cat5, 5e or 6.  The ones you link to have no such rating, but the ones that I purchase  do.

Comment: @sawdust - could you link the ones you've purchased for reference ?

Comment: I have several from M*******e.com, but a google search such as "Cat5e coupler" will turn up what I mean.